# Where can I find a list of Visual Studio 2015 Extension Installation Targets?

Tags: visual-studio

I have an Extension to print Visual Studio source code in color. I have set the  in the Manifests file as:

```
 <Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="14.0" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" Version="14.0" />
  </Installation>
```

How do I amend this list to make sure that my Extension is available for **all** editions of Visual Studio 2015?